# Cannot append to an element in popup.html for chrome plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins

I'm creating my first plugin and it's function is to scrape reviews from third party retailers like Walmart and Best Buy to provide additional reviews to Amazon shoppers. I've been able to log the reviews in the console, but I'm getting stuck at the final step where I need to append (content.js) it to the element 'reviews' (popup.html). The error I get in the console is "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null**". I suspect that content.js is unable to see popup.html as it is another window, therefore unable to append elements to it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Also on a side note, I'm not sure if background.js is still relevant as it was created with the getting started tutorial. I'm only able to use the chrome plugin at *developer.chrome.com* and nowhere else. How would I get this to work on *amazon.com*?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Reviews",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Get additional product reviews",
  "permissions": [
    "https://www.walmart.com/*",
    "http://www.walmart.com/*",
    "https://www.amazon.com/*",
    "http://www.amazon.com/*",
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**package-lock.json**

```
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "fetch-jsonp": {
      "version": "1.1.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fetch-jsonp/-/fetch-jsonp-1.1.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-nrnlhboIqvcAVjU40Xu+u81aPbI="
    }
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="reviews-btn">Get Reviews</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <ul id="reviews"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
'use strict';

let getReview = document.getElementById('reviews-btn');

getReview.onclick = function(element) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: "content.js"
  });
};
```

**content.js**

```
fetch("https://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/search?apiKey=vck5ypdbw4jnhuceesmjjce5&query=NETGEAR&format=json")
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (responseText) {
  if (responseText) {
    var product = responseText.items[0];
    var itemId = product.itemId;
    fetch(`https://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/reviews/${itemId}?apiKey=vck5ypdbw4jnhuceesmjjce5&format=json`)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function (responseText) {
      var reviews = document.getElementById('reviews');
      var walmartReviews = responseText.reviews
      for (i in walmartReviews) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = walmartReviews[i].reviewText;
        reviews.append(li);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({color: '#3aa757'}, function() {
    console.log('The color is green.');
  });
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'developer.chrome.com'},
      })
      ],
          actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to get a reference to the popup window, and then use `popupWindow.document.getElementById('reviews')`. But I don't see where your code is opening the popup window.

Comment: I'm unsure if it's actually considered a popup window in the background. With the chrome plugin, it's accessible as an icon in the top right corner of the browser window. When clicked, a small styled html comes up (popup.html) with the 'Get Reviews' button. Click the button, and it will log the reviews from Walmart in the console. I'm having trouble outputting that into the popup.html with content.js because I suspect that content.js doesn't see popup.html, that's why I'm getting the error property of null. Just my theory thus far.

Comment: Where do you tell it to use `popup.html`? I don't see any mention of that filename in your code.

Comment: I've tried using `popupWindow.document.getElementById('reviews')` but I got a Reference Error: popupWindow is not defined.

Comment: That was a placeholder, you're supposed to replace it with the actual variable containing the window that you opened.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: I see it used to be in manifest.json. I must've deleted it on accident.

Comment: OK. Code in `popup.js` can access the popup window's DOM. Code in `content.js` can access the main window's DOM. You can use message passing between them to update the popup.